# How to eleminate duplicate records from mysql query

Tags: mysql, performance, join, inner-join, outer-join

I have one application where I have to show user's activities. I am facing one problem regarding duplicate entry/activities. First of all I have describe my schema:

## Table: UserFriends

```
CREATE TABLE `testDb`.`UserFriends` (
  `Pk` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Userid` INT NULL,
  `Friendid` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Pk`));
```

## Table: UserActivities

```
CREATE TABLE `testDb`.`UserActivities` (
  `Pk` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `Userid` INT NULL,
  `Friendid` INT NULL,
  `ActivityType` TINYINT(1) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Pk`));
```

Insert some dummy data into the tables.

```
INSERT INTO UserFriends(Userid, friendid )
values (7,105), (7,92)  

INSERT INTO UserActivities(Userid, friendid )
values (92, 1054), (105,2014), (92,105)
```

I have one user (pk - 7) in UserFriends table with 2 friends (e.g. id no(s) 105 & 92). There is some activities which is done by user (eg.7) and its friends. User 92 has become friends with user 1054, user 105 has added user 2014 as a friend and user 92 and user 105 also become a friend. Now I have to show user 7 to his/her activities. I have create a query which is fined all activities of user itself as well as it's all friends. Here is the query :

```
select ua.pk activityid, 
    if(uf.Friendid = ua.userid, ua.userid, ua.Friendid) myfriend,       
    if(uf.Friendid = ua.Friendid, ua.Friendid, ua.Userid) friend_of_friend
from UserFriends uf 
inner join UserActivities ua on uf.Friendid = if(uf.Friendid = ua.userid, ua.userid, ua.Friendid)
where uf.userid = 7
```

and I have got result as follows :

```
activityid,   myfriend,   friend_of_friend
1,            92,         1054
2,            105,        2014
3,            105,        92
3,            92,         105
```

Please check result carefully, there is a duplicate records come for activity id 3 due to join. User 7 has two friends (eg. 92, 105), so it comes twice. I want only one records. I don't know how to remove/eliminate this records. My original query has 6-7 table join and ***activity*** table has about 600000 records and ***userfriend*** table as around 200000 records. so I have to consider performance too. 
Please anyone can help to me to solve this problem. 
thanks.

Comment: you should use the `DISTINCT`.

Comment: Which of the 'duplicated' rows is the wrong one?

Comment: do you want like this [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/edce6/4] source from `echo_Me` and `DISTINCT` from suggesition [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/edce6/6]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try add `GROUP BY activityid`

like that :

```
    where uf.userid = 7
    GROUP BY activityid
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this query

```
select DISTINCT ua.pk activityid, 
    if(uf.Friendid = ua.userid, ua.userid, ua.Friendid) myfriend,       
    if(uf.Friendid = ua.Friendid, ua.Friendid, ua.Userid) friend_of_friend
from UserFriends uf 
inner join UserActivities ua on uf.Friendid = if(uf.Friendid = ua.userid, ua.userid, ua.Friendid)
where uf.userid = 7
```

I have used a distinct keyword before `ua.pk`.

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Comment: thanks for reply, I have tried this, but it is not work in my case